# how to disable button after clicked it

Tags: android, button

I want to disable a button after a click is performed.

```
        bwasta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btDes);

        final Button bwasta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btDes);

        bwasta.setEnabled(false);

        bwasta.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                bwasta.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: do you have a listener for your click?

Comment: Please look at [ask].

Answer (score 1):

put `bwasta.setEnabled(false);` in your `onClick()` method.

set onClickListener first in your `onCreate` method:

```
button.setOnClickListener(mListener);
```

then:

```
private View.OnClickListener mListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            bwasta.setEnabled(false);

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
final Button myButtom = Button) findViewById(R.id.btDes);;
        myButtom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View view) {
                myButtom.setEnabled(false);

                //do something

                myButtom.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the clickability in the click listener.

```
bwasta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(View view) {
    test.setClickable(false);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;

bwasta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(count == 0){
                    bwasta.isEnabled();
                    count++;
                }else if (count >= 1)
                    bwasta.setClickable(false);
            }
        });
```